# Why isn't there aberration in parabolic mirrors?

Tags: optics, reflection

It is known that aberration happens in spherical mirrors due to the fact that all reflected lights doesn't pass through the focal point. But how would you prove this doesn't happen on parabolic mirrors, using the mathematical definition of a parabola.

[image]

can you mathematically show that the black light rays will always pass through the focus after they are reflected.

Comment: HI! Your diagram is partially incorrect, because not all, but only the rays parallel to the axis of the parabola pass through its focus on reflection.

Comment: Only light that is parallel to the axis of revolution of the parabola (i.e. on-axis and collimated) will go through focus. For objects that are far away enough - stars - this is always the case.

Comment: [Probable Duplicate](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/323701/for-the-derivation-of-the-form-of-a-paraboloidal-reflector-there-is-much-more-i?rq=1) except the answer there is not necessarily clear.

Comment: Are you familiar with the co-ordinate geometry of the parabola, including the use of the $t$ parameter?

Comment: There is a geometric proof on the Wikipedia page for the parabola, if that's good enough for you https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parabola#Proof_of_the_reflective_property

Comment: There is no *spheric* aberration for parabolas, which is not surprising, since parabolic mirrors are not spherical – there are other kinds of aberration.